# Why does the Knapsack Problem DP using tabular method discretize the capacity?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming

I am trying to learn different aspect of DP and the first thing that pops on google search for "Knapsack 0-1" is this

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-dynamic-programming-set-10-0-1-knapsack-problem/

```
# A Dynamic Programming based Python 
# Program for 0-1 Knapsack problem
# Returns the maximum value that can 
# be put in a knapsack of capacity W
def knapSack(W, wt, val, n):
    K = [[0 for x in range(W + 1)] for x in range(n + 1)]
  
    # Build table K[][] in bottom up manner
    for i in range(n + 1):
        for w in range(W + 1):
            if i == 0 or w == 0:
                K[i][w] = 0
            elif wt[i-1] <= w:
                K[i][w] = max(val[i-1] + K[i-1][w-wt[i-1]],  K[i-1][w])
            else:
                K[i][w] = K[i-1][w]
  
    return K[n][W]
  
# Driver program to test above function
val = [60, 100, 120]
wt = [10, 20, 30]
W = 50
n = len(val)
print(knapSack(W, wt, val, n))
  
# This code is contributed by Bhavya Jain
```

I stopped at the first line. Why does the code create a matrix of n by W discretizing W with one unit? Why one was chosen? What if W is very big (example W=10000000000) ? Wouldn't the matrix overflow the memory ? What if the capacity W is a decimal number for example 50.6?

Strangely, the first video tutorial that pops on youtube shows the same approach https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLmhmB6NzcM

Comment: Sensible points. You could replace the W-sized array with a dictionary if you expected it to need only a small (relative to W) number of non-zero values.

Comment: It's true that 0-1 knapsack has an FPTAS, but that's not what's typically shown (not at first anyway, maybe later)